# Universal links don't open in Safari

Tags: ios, safari, ios-universal-links

I setup everything according to the [Manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html), and it seems like in general it works. Universal link leads to my app and with proper location. It opens from everywhere (Mail, Notes etc) but not in Safari. Safari is just loading the real web page. When I do long tap on the link in Safari, there appears a popup with options, and my App is in there.
Maybe I don't completely understand the sense of the universal links? Does it work correctly?

Comment: Keep in mind that if the user choses safari for the first time when opening an universal link, the OS will pick safari instead of your app, until the user long presses on the link and in the list of apps picks your app. No library can fix that, is how iOS and universal links work.

Comment: can you please give me the link to documentation where it's mentioned?

Comment: Check this troubleshooting: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1916/_index.html it states clearly to "Long press" also check the "Step 6 or 7 failed" part.

Answer (score 0):

Recommendation: you can use **[Branch SDK](https://branch.io/)** 
it takes about 5 minutes to make and handle everything you need

**[Branch SDK](https://branch.io/)** is an SDK for implementing a universal link, handling the Deeplink routing logic you need not handle any of the use cases that you have mentioned

Follow the docs below for integrating Branch SDK:

Docs Here https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/ios/